# How can I get value from IDictionary ? When I try I got "does not contain method TryGetValue" error

Tags: c#, contains, trygetvalue

I have an IDictionary  object , my question is how I can read data by key? 
It looks easier question but there is no method (even similiar one is not found) like **TryGetValue** .
Only **Contains** method looks available, but I want to get value of data by key.

Am I missing stg?

Edit:
As detail

I am trying to get values from:

```
var browser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;
```

I want to get value from the `IDictionary` object(named `Capabilities`) which is defined inside `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser`:

```
public IDictionary Capabilities { get; set; }
```

When I try to read value from this object, I can not.

Comment: Use the indexer `dict[key]`?

Comment: `IDictionary` does not have a method `TryGetValue`.

Comment: _Why_ do you have a nongeneric `IDictionary` object to begin with? `TryGetValue()` is defined in the generic `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface.

Comment: You're looking for [IDictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) but you have [IDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Look at the docs of `IDictionary`. There exists an indexer, which you can use exacty as you intend: `dict[key]`.

Comment: I had already tried accessing by index but does not work, it says "can not apply indexing with to an expression of type  ICollection"

Comment: You said you had an `IDictionary`.  Now its an `ICollection`?

Comment: @Amy no , I have IDictionary Capabilities { get; set; }    but  adviced to access by index , I replied I had already tired this and got   error like previous comment.   ICollection Keys { get; }  are included in IDictonary.

Comment: Yes, `IDictionary` has a property `Keys`, but you were advised to use `Capabilities["key"]`.  It is unclear what the issue is now.

Comment: Ohh thanks. I must have been experienced so busy day, how I missed this stuff:) But I would want to use TryGetValue  , but it looks impossible

Comment: @Ozmen [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270514/how-can-i-get-value-from-idictionary-when-i-try-i-got-does-not-contain-method#comment104748204_59270514)

Comment: I don't think `Capabilities` is intended for public use, `HttpBrowserCapabilities` implements an indexer property directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write an extension method for `HttpBrowserCapabilities`:

```
public static class CapExt {
    public static bool TryGetValue(this HttpBrowserCapabilities b, string key, out string value) => (value = (string)b[key]) != null;
}
```

Or for `IDictionary`:

```
public static class IDictionaryExt {
    public static bool TryGetValue(this IDictionary d, object key, out object value) => (value = d[key]) != null;
}
```